# Kivy app takes 30 seconds to open

Tags: android, python, ios, python-2.7, kivy

It is taking about 30 seconds to open a Kivy app on iOS and Android devices (it takes only 3 seconds to open on Mac OSX... haven't tried it on Windows). The kivy-ios package is used to build the app for iOS and buildozer is used to build the app for Android.

The console log for opening the app on an iPhone is below. I'm at a loss as to what is causing the slow start time.

```
Aug 19 13:29:29 My-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2943] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/5CCB9A16-0288-4075-8269-212FD5AB2767 (sandbox)
Aug 19 13:29:29 My-iPhone backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'my_app' access to protected services is denied.
Aug 19 13:29:30 My-iPhone my_app[2943] <Warning>: PythonHome is: /var/mobile/Applications/5CCB9A16-0288-4075-8269-212FD5AB2767/my_app.app
Aug 19 13:29:30 My-iPhone my_app[2943] <Warning>: Initializing python
Aug 19 13:29:31 My-iPhone my_app[2943] <Warning>: Running main.pyo: /var/mobile/Applications/5CCB9A16-0288-4075-8269-212FD5AB2767/my_app.app/YourApp/main.pyo
Aug 19 13:29:31 My-iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 2caa7
Aug 19 13:29:31 My-iPhone SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003
Aug 19 13:29:31 My-iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
```

EDIT: The app takes almost 30 seconds to open on first launch and on subsequent launches.

Comment: Usually when building apps in the cross platform tools it packages the utilities required to run the apps with the distributed app. It could be that in order to run it through python it has to install/commit to memory all files required for use and then run the app.

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but on Android the Python code is extracted from a zip file - the first run of any app will take longer than usual. Does it take this long on every run or just the first? A simple app on my Android tablet takes 3 seconds to launch (after the first run).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ryan P said in a comment, the first run will take longer, but it shouldn't need 30s.

One thing that's often important is that the app not only does some necessary unpacking (on the first run) and app initialisation (on every run), but also runs the code in your main.py and anything in the app build() method. If this is significant, it will take some time, but the user won't see anything during this time. You can avoid that problem by starting with only a minimal gui and loading the rest more lazily.

You may also want to benchmark your performance against another kivy app, such as the [kivy 2048](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meltingrocks.kivy2048) on the play store. I don't know if Mathieu spent much time optimising for this in particular, but it should behave at least very reasonably. If it's much faster to load than yours, the problem lies with your code/apk.

We usually suggest that kivy should need no more than a small number of seconds to do its init (especially after the first run), often less than a second for apps on newer devices that are careful about it.

Edit: I should clarify that the above is from my knowledge of Kivy's android toolchain. I don't know about any of the specifics of ios, though it's something very similar and you can expect similar things to be important.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. But the app takes about 30 seconds to launch on subsequent launches, not just during the first launch. I've just edited the question w this info.

Comment: I thought this would probably be the case (the first run doesn't make *that* much difference unless the apk is very big and the sdcard is slow), the rest of it is what's really important.